# Retrieving the data from firebase real-time database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to ionic. I created an ionic app and in that used firebase authentication. When I login in my ionic app with email and password it navigates to profile page. In the profile page, when the user submitted the details the data will be stored in the **firebase real-time database**. But when I try to retrieve that data I'm not getting any data from my **firebase real-time database** and showing the error like this.

```
InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'.
```

Here is the Error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCqRn.png

Here is the `dashboard.page.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import {
  ToastController,
  NavController,
  LoadingController,
} from "@ionic/angular";
import { Profile } from "../models/profile";
import { AngularFireObject } from "angularfire2/database";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dashboard.page.scss"],
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
  profileData: AngularFireObject<Profile>;
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private toast: ToastController,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private LoadCtrl: LoadingController,

    private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
        this.toast
          .create({
            message: `Welcome to Manoj_APP, ${data.email}`,
            duration: 2000,
          })
          .then((toastData) => toastData.present());
        this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`);
      } else {
        this.toast
          .create({
            message: `Could Not Find Authentication details`,
            duration: 2000,
          })
          .then((toastData) => toastData.present());
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("tabs/tab1");
      }
    });
  }

  async logout() {
    let loader = this.LoadCtrl.create({
      message: "Loging Out",
      duration: 3000,
    });
    await (await loader).present();
    try {
      await this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("tabs/tab1");
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Logout Failed");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the `dashboard.component.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-tab-menu slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-tab-menu>
    <ion-title>Welcome Here</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <p>Username :{{(profileData | async)?.firstName}}</p>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <p>First Name :{{(profileData | async)?.lastName}}</p>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <p>Last Name :{{(profileData | async)?.username}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar>
    <ion-tab-button (click)="logout()">
      <ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Logout</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of

```
profileData: AngularFireObject<Profile>;
```

write

```
profileData: Observable<Profile>;
```

and

```
this.profileData = this.afData
          .object(`profile/${data.uid}`);
```

to

```
this.profileData = this.afData
          .object<Profile>(`profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
```